# How to remove the padding of the indicatorContainer (first child of IndicatorsContainer)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I am trying to make the size of the react-select's Select component smaller. Everything works pretty well with one exception.

The element whose padding I wish to remove has this class: `css-tlfecz-indicatorContainer` and is a subcomponent of the react-select `Select` component, more precisely, the subcomponent responsible of rendering the × sign for clearing the selection.

I have tried putting this in the styles prop of the Select:

```js
indicatorsContainer: (provided, state) => {
  return {
    ...provided,
    padding: '0px',
    paddingLeft: '0px',
    paddingTop: '0px',
    paddingRight: '0px',
    paddingDown: '0px',
  };
},
```

But it does not work. I expected that there was an indicatorContainer styleable component, so that I do not have to override components with my own components, but I think this is the only way.

A screenshot of how the Select looks like if I change the styles manually from the DevTools' Elements tab:

[image: screenshot]

There are no error messages.

Thank you.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan The height of the Select should match the height of the toolbar in which it is placed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the snippet in the question I just had to replace `indicatorsContainer` with `clearIndicator`. This `clearIndicator` is not rendered with a class like `clearIndicator` but with `indicatorContainer` (without `s` after `indicator`) and this confused me.

Comment: This little inconsistency shows how otherwise consistent this library is :D

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to style `dropdownIndicator` and `clearIndicator` instead of `indicatorContainer`.